# How can I scroll a whole page like an e-reader in Firefox on a tablet

Tags: firefox, touchscreen, tablet

Since I have a smartphone, I notice that scrolling web pages is a strain on my eyes. The moving of content across the page forces my eyes to follow it, which feels strainful for me. This is worse on a tablet as the screen is bigger. I really like the e-reader style, where you can tap on the screen to scroll one page.

On a notebook, this is no problem as I can easily use the PgDown key. But on my Windows tablet, this key is of course not available. I looked for Firefox extensions that might do this by googling "Firefox touchscreen scroll one page" and "Firefox tap to scroll", but the search results deal only with how to get Firefox to "drag-to-scroll" on a (Linux) tablet. But I want the opposite! I want Firefox to scroll down one page when I tap on the page!

How can I do this? It would be great to use my tablet to read newspapers, but its not really relaxing like this.

(P.S. currently I use Windows but I plan to switch to Ubuntu. So I appreciate answers for Windows and Linux)